# Perforce Delete all History

Tags: perforce

I have a perforce project that had a few rather large folders added/removed in it's history. My team has multiple backups and our storage space is limited so I would like to obliterate everything except the current revision. Is there any way to do this with the p4v client or in a linux server command line (where the perforce server is)? Alternatively, in the server side is there a folder I can delete everything from and just upload a new fresh copy? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this from P4V, in the Admin view: *Tools-->Administration* and click on the *Depots* tab.

From there, find the file(s) or directory you want to obliterate and choose *Obliterate...* It's very nifty, in that it lets you obliterate all revisions or a range of revisions.

STANDARD CAVEAT: If you choose to go this route, it's permanent. It will get rid of the files on your server (and free up the disk space they currently use up).

Comment: Note: Do not forget to create database backup before obliterating. Couple of years ago I experienced that obliterate failed with strange errors and it was hard to tell whether the database is OK since that point. It was kind of test run, so reinstalling Perforce helped, but I would not want to see this in production.

Comment: ^^^ Can't be said enough.

Comment: This seemed to work great, removing unneeded folders/files from the depo and freeing up space. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
echo list -l current ...#head > cmds
echo files -a "@<current"    >> cmds
p4 -x cmds run
```

Run it like that first -- when you've satisfied yourself that you want to get rid of all that forever, replace "files -a" with "obliterate -y" and do it again.

Comment: This probably works good, wouldn't let me double answer it and I chose the visual answer below, thanks though, very helpful code, I'll probably need the command line method down the line : ' )